# ActiveMQ - Competing Consumers with Selector - messages starve in the queue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

ActiveMQ 5.15.13

**Context**: I have a single queue with multiple Consumers. I want to stop some consumers from processing certain messages. This has to be dynamic, I don't want to create separate queues for this. This works without any problems. e.g. `Consumer1 ignores Stocks` -> `Consumer1` can process all `invoices` and `Consumer2` can process all `Stocks`

But if there is a large number of messages already in the Queue (of one type, e.g. `stocks`) and I send a message of another type (e.g. `invoices`), `Consumer1` won't process the message of type `invoices`. It will instead be idle until `Consumer2` has processed all `Stocks` messages. It does not happen every time, but quite often.

Is there any option to change the order of the new messages coming into the queue, such that an idle consumer with matching selector picks up the new message?

**Things I've already tried:**

- using a [PendingMessageLimitStrategy](https://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling) -> it seems like it does not work for queues
- increasing the [maxPageSize and maxBrowsePageSize](https://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies) in the hope that once all Messages are in RAM, the Consumers will search for their messages.
- [Exclusive Consumers](https://activemq.apache.org/exclusive-consumer) aren't an option since I want to be able to use more than one Consumer per message type.

Im pretty sure that there is some configuration which allows this type of usage. I'm aware that there are better solutions for this issue, but sadly I can't use them easily due to other constraints.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:** I noticed that when I'm refreshing on the localhost [queue browser](http://localhost:8161/admin/browse.jsp?JMSDestination=parser-local), the stuck messages get executed immediately. It seems like this action performs some sort of queue refresh where the messages get filtered based on their selector again. So I just need this action whenever a new message enters the queue...

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'window' problem where the next set of 'stocks' data needs to be processed before the 'invoicing' data can be processed.

The gotcha with window problems like this is that you need to account for the fact that some messages may *never* come through, or a consumer may never come back online either. Also, eventually you will be asked 'how many invoices or stocks are left to be processed'-- aka observability.

ActiveMQ has you covered-- check out wild-card destinations and consumers.

Produce 'stocks' to:

```
queue://data.stocks.input
```

Produce 'invoices' to:

```
queue://data.invoices.input
```

You then setup consumes to connect:

```
queue://data.*.input
```

note: the wildard '*'.

ActiveMQ will match queues based on the wildcard pattern, and then process data accordingly. As a bonus, you can still use a selector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) wild-card destinations do not look like what I need. The problem is that the types are dynamic :( Sadly, i don't know the set of types... Probably this was unclear in the question in the first place. What currently works for me is the update via the queue browser (see the edit). I mimic this with a call to the `QueueBrowser`.